# Linq - Using linq to do order by one between three fields (datetime)

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, sql-order-by

I have the following class:

```
public class Operacao : Valor<Operacao>
{
    public DateTime DataDeAdicao { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataDeAlteracao { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataDeExclusao { get; set; }
}
```

All of my main classes inherit from this class.

I need a query using `linq`, to return me the values ordered by the maximum date between those three fields.

I tried something like the following:

```
.OrderBy(f => new[] { f.Operacao.DataDeAdicao, f.Operacao.DataDeAlteracao, f.Operacao.DataDeExclusao }.Max())
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" - doesn't compile?  doesn't give you the right results?

Comment: Also what is `f` in your example?  a class that has a `Operacao` property?

Comment: Doesn't give the right results.

Comment: "f" is a class that inherits from "Operacao" class

Comment: It does give the right results, you would want to create a separate test for some sample data and see if it works. Then, when it passes try examining actual data against expected results.

Answer (score 3):

```
IEnumerable<Operacao> collection  = ...;
var ordered = collection
    .OrderBy(op => new[] {op.DataDeAdicao, op.DataDeAlteracao, op.DataDeExclusao}.Max());
```